# Passing data from child form to parent form

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control in a child form and it captures some data from the displayed web page. I need to use this data in the browser form to be passed to the parent form, but without having to start a new instance of it as it's already open.

The parent form needs to recieve this data from the browser and update some textboxes with the variables set from parsing the page.

I have this in the parent form:

```
private void browserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(RunBrowser));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start(); 
    }

    public static void RunBrowser()
    {
        Application.Run(new BrowserForm());
    }
```

I have tried many things in the child form, but I cannot get it to work at all. The best I can get is to pass a variable to the parent and display it via a MessageBox, but it refuses to update the TextBox at all.

BTW I have been trying to solve this now for nearly 12 hours straight, that is the only reason I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it finally, but not in an ideal way.

In the parent I open it like this:

```
    private void BrowserToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        using (BrowserForm form = new BrowserForm())
        {
            form.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

I have this method in the Parent also:

```
    public void SendStringsToParent(string s, string s2, string s3)
    {
        textBox.Text = s;
        textBox2.Text = s2;
        textBox3.Text = s3;
    }
```

Then in the Child (Browser) form I have this:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stringToSend = "sending these";
        string stringToSend2 = "strings to the";
        string stringToSend3 = "parent form";
        MainForm parent = (MainForm)this.Owner;
        parent.SendStringsToParent(stringToSend, stringToSend2, stringToSend3);
    }
```

This is working, although I have had to work around the fact that it is a modal form. If there is any way to do this this while still having full control over both forms, I would love to hear from someone.

Answer (score 0):

Please check For this Method..

But if you are passing private data this not will be helpful.

In Your Browser page:

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
      string modulename = "Agile Software Development ";
      string url;



      url = "page2.aspx?module=" +modulename;
      Response.Redirect(url);
```

}

In Your Parent page

string RetrievedValue;protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
      this.TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["module"];

    //  RetrievedValue = this.TextBox1.Text;
```

}